# i am trying to use a switch statement when someone inputs a month in a text box and hits submit will display out a message in PHP

Tags: php

Okay so i have created a switch statement and want to integrate a text box so when the user enters a month and hits submit a message will display for each month. what am i missing i think i am close to getting this complete:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
Enter a month: <input type = "text" name ="month">
<input type = "submit">
</form>
<?php
switch($month){
case december:
    echo " its a chilly winter";
    break;
case january:
    echo " its a chilly winter";
    break;
case febraury:
    echo " its a chilly winter";
    break;
case march:
    echo " its a beautiful spring";
    break;
case april:
    echo " its a beautiful spring";
    break;
case may:
    echo " its a beautiful spring";
    break;
case june:
    echo " the heat of summer";
    break;
case july:
    echo " the heat of summer";
    break;
case august:
    echo " the heat of summer";
    break;
default: 
    echo "please enter a month.";
}
?>
```

Comment: The value is text so it needs to be wrapped in quotes like `case 'december':`

Answer (score 1):

Two issues that prevent it from working:

- Quote the case values `"december"` or `'december'`
- The value from the form comes in the `$_POST` array as `$_POST['month']`

So for a start:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
Enter a month: <input type="text"   name="month">
               <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
switch(strtolower($_POST['month'])){
    case "december":
    case "january":
    case "february":
        echo " its a chilly winter";
        break;
    case "march":
    case "april":
    case "may":
        echo " its a beautiful spring";
        break;
    case "june":
    case "july":
    case "august":
        echo " the heat of summer";
        break;
    default: 
        echo "please enter a month.";
}
```

Also, if you put them in order to "fall through" you don't need repetitive code in each of the cases.  Here if you input `december` it will end up at `february` (since there are no `break` statements) and echo the same message.

You can also add `strtolower()` so that if `DECEMBER` is entered it will be converted and still match `december`.

You will probably need to add `name="something"` (I used `submit`) to the submit so that you can later check that the form has been submitted with:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //do stuff
}
```

While developing/testing, make sure to display errors with this before any code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

BTW, where is *september, october, november*???

Comment: @calastinone: Accept the answer if it helped, thanks!